# Single element (ul) View in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to create a View in backbone which is an "ul", I need to be able to instanciate this view into another view, and all the li child elements need to be filled with an _.each... However, I'm trying to figure it out which is the best way to do it.

I would appreciate any kind of help to point in the right direction... so the case is:

```
 App.Views.BulkResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
   tagName : 'ul',
   className : 'bulk_results',

   //THIS IS BAD AND I KNOW IT
   template: _.template("
              <% _.each(results, function(result) { %>
                  <li><%= result %></li>
              <% } %>"), 

   initialize : function() {
        this.render();
   },

   render : function() {
       this.$el.html( this.template(  { results : App.bulkResults.toJSON() } ) );
       return this;
   }
 });
```

I know the way I'm defining the template it is bad, I'm not even sure if I can include a _.each statement into it, therefore, could anyone help a brother out?

Best Regards

Comment: why do you think it's bad ? I prefer to have inline-templates for templates with less than 50 lines of code. And yes, you can include a `_.each`. The only reason to break views into smaller pieces is only if each individual piece can be used as a significant component at other places without any change.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the problems that Marionette addresses really well, it provides a good of defaults that reduce some boilerplate code, collection and item views are good examples here.

Here is a simple example that you can review and see if it is good for your needs

```
BookItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({    
    tagName: 'li', 
    template: '#itemView-template'    
});

BookCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({    
    tagName: 'ul', 
    childView: BookItemView     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arturo_pst/qxj1xLj1/21/

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md

Comment: this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid... to create 2 different views for the ul and li.

Comment: Well, definitely this is one of the best ways to implement this, but probably doesn't feet your needs, I think that you need to provide more details about why you don't want to create 2 diff views, without context is difficult to provide a more accurate answer